# How to push Every N times the firsts N elements from one array to another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

am wonder how to do this one, can you help me to learn how to think and solve this kind of problem, please?

in this example i will use 8 like N

```
let original = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

//to 

let modified  = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[9,10]]
```

for example if i use a `Array.slice` and i have  more than the example number like 19 elements inside `original` i need to create a new array  inside to `modified`

and should be look like this :

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[17,18,19]]
```

is dynamic

Comment: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/chunk.js  For a reference of how lodash does chunk, which is essentially what you are asking for

Comment: @HernanHumaña - I've updated my answer if you care to take a look. My answer is much simpler than the lodash solution or the other provided answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.slice()` to pull out the parts needed.

You should read the docs for [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

The way to think about this is "I want part of the array". In JavaScript you retrieve part of an array by using `.slice()`.

Since you have an unknown number of elements, you can use a `while` loop and shorten the array on each loop. The loop should exit when there are less elements than the size you want (8). Then, add the remaining elements. All of this still using slice.

```js
let original = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19];
let out = [];
while (original.length > 8) {
  out.push(original.slice(0, 8));
  original = original.slice(8);
}
out.push(original);
console.log(out);
```

Comment: you are right! the problem is that is every 8 times that means that if in the next one is more than 8 numbers, should be create a new array in the ```out```

Comment: My answer is based upon your input. If you need an answer based upon different input parameters you should include the exact input that you are having difficulty with. I'll help you solve the problem if you state it clearly in your question. Please edit your question and provide the correct input.

Comment: answer has been updated to reflect your edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I will do that this way:

```js
let original_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  , original_2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]


const arrayCut = (arr, count) => arr.reduce((a,c,i)=>
  {
  let aN = Math.floor(i/count)
  if (!(i%count)) a.push([])
  a[aN].push(c)
  return(a)
  },[])

let mod_1 = arrayCut( original_1, 8 )
  , mod_2 = arrayCut( original_2, 8 )

console.log('mod_1', JSON.stringify(mod_1))
console.log('mod_2', JSON.stringify(mod_2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```